# Error Activemq-storage - Lorg/apache/activemq/store/kahadb/plist/PListStore - wildfly - java 8

Tags: java, spring, wildfly

I've this error when I run my .war in wildfly:

```
Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.activemq.usage.TempUsage.getStore()Lorg/apache/activemq/store/kahadb/plist/PListStore;
```

My pom is as follows:

```
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
        <artifactId>activemq-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.5.1</version>            
    </dependency>   
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
        <artifactId>activemq-broker</artifactId>
        <version>5.10.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
        <artifactId>activemq-pool</artifactId>
        <version>5.10.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
        <artifactId>activemq-spring</artifactId>
        <version>5.10.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
        <artifactId>artemis-jms-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.19.0</version>
    </dependency>
        
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
        <artifactId>activemq-kahadb-store</artifactId>
        <version>5.10.1</version>
    </dependency>   

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
        <artifactId>activemq-jdbc-store</artifactId>
        <version>5.10.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

I used to have activemq-all but i take it out because it gave me and error slf4j duplicate bindings, so I decided to put dependencies separately. Maybe, do I need another dependency to avoid the error?. Any idea how to solve it?.

Comment: Mixing 5.5 and 5.10 versions of ActiveMQ. Never mix jars from different versions of a framework.

Comment: Also 5.10 is quite older than the 2.19 version of the `artemis-jms-client` so you need to have versions from around the same time for compatibility.

Comment: the full version of WildFly delivers ActiveMQ out of the box. You can find your queue in code by: @Resource(mappedName = "java:/jms/queue/myQueue")